# TypeError 'x' is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TypeError: this.props.handleClick is not a function

```
class Task extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="Task">
                <span style = {{ textDecoration : this.props.todo.done ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>{this.props.todo.value}</span> 
                <button onClick = {() => this.props.handleClick(this.props.index)}>{this.props.todo.done ? 'Undo' : 'Complete'}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Probably you forgot to specify `handleClick` in `<Task>`

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help you, we need a [mcve]. You're receiving this error because `this.props.handleClick` is undefined–which would be caused by a parent component. Please post more relevant code.

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?  What's your question?

Comment: i have added handle click in <Task>

Comment: Heres the full code that i have written
https://www.codepile.net/pile/k5j6DA5o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you better pass handleClick to your component as a prop, and make sure it is a function.

Comment: Heres the full code that i have written codepile.net/pile/k5j6DA5o

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/k5j6DA5o

Comment: your List component doesn't have a handleClick passed to it. That's why Task in its turn doesn't have it too.

Comment: thanks sir that solved the problem