# TypeError: this.props.handleClick is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have a app components with two child components Conter and Button. When the button is clicked the counter should increment. So I maintain a state in the app component and it has a function handleClick() which is passed as a prop to button component.

```js
import React from  'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      value: 0,
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log("handleClick")
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value + 1,
    });
  }

  

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="frame">
        <Counter value={this.state.value} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} />
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    
    return <h1> {this.props.value} </h1>
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // console.log("inside button")
    return <button onClick={() => {
      this.props.handleClick();
      
    }}>  Click </button>
  }
}



export default App;
```

But when I click on the button I get the error as

```
App.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.handleClick is not a function
    at onClick (App.js:43:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
```

I did go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60911291/why-is-one-of-my-child-components-able-to-get-handleclick-but-the-others-are-n) and [[TypeError 'x' is not a function [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550841/typeerror-x-is-not-a-function)][2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550841/typeerror-x-is-not-a-function) but didnot find my solution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed your `handleClick` function as `onClick` prop so you must call it with `this.props.onClick()` inside child component

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // console.log("inside button")
    return <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>  Click </button>
  }
}
```